# Plotting vectors originating from the origin in 3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization

I have an array of data with 3D elements. Ex: `x = {{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}, {5,6,7}}`.
I want to show this data in 3 dimensions, such that each point in the space is shown as a vector originating from the origin. There should be an arrow/line whose one end is at the origin $(0,0,0)$ and the other end at the point $(1,2,3)$.

Which function should I use?

Comment: Very well explained.  Welcome to Mathematica.SE!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For your problem, it is probably easiest to build the graphic out of [graphics primitives](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphicsAndSoundOverview.html) rather than use a pre-made convenience function such as `ListPointPlot3D`.

This is one way to do it:

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}};

Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I simply used the `Arrow` graphics primitive.  I constructed a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) that makes an arrow starting from the origin, and mapped it over the data.

Comment: Do you know how to show the grid inside the box?

Answer (score 10):

I wasn't able to find a way to make `ListPointPlot3D` draw lines instead of points.

As an alternative to Szabolcs' `Graphics3D`, here is a slightly different way using `ParametricPlot3D` and a replacement rule.

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}};
ParametricPlot3D[data*u, {u, 0, 1}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many good answers to this problem. Another is to use `Arrow` function:

```
Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 4}}]], Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Comment: This is the same what the accepted answer suggests.