# How to plot and visualize a single linear vector in 3D?

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra, physics

I have a vector (in physic) designated as F1=250cos(60)i+250cos(60)j+250cos(45)k, and i would like to see it in a 3D graphic with the axis centered at the origin, after what i would include other vector from there.
But i have been unable to graph it.
I have tried this:

```
    Plot3D[{250*cos[60], 250*cos[60], -250*cos[45]}, {x, -20, 20}]

    VectorPlot3D[{250*cos[60]*x, 250*cos[60]*y, -250*cos[45]*z}, {x, -20, 
                20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}]
    Plot3D[{250*cos[60]*x, 250*cos[60]*y, -250*cos[45]*z}, {x, -20, 
           20}, {y, -20, 20}]
```

I know why it doesn`t work, (i,j,k are not variabe but a direction!) but i still dont see how to get the vector to show up?

Any suggestion.

(first time user, would appreciate as much info as possible)

Thanks in advance

Seb.

[image: Vector in Space]

Comment: See e.g. [Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt/18612#18612)

Comment: Mathematica functions (Cos in this case) always start with a capital letter. Go biometric functions take radians as argument. Multiply an angle value in degrees with the built-in constant `Degree` to convert that value to radians. Furthermore, in your last line of code, z is undefined.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: HAAHAA, The capital letter is a good beginning, thks @SjoerdC.deVries, but what is the biometric function ?

Comment: I<m sorry, like a said before i<m new to this...

Comment: My iPad autocorected or so. Should be trigonometric function.

Comment: By the way, can you see what i<m trying to do here, plotting the vector in 3D space. ? Can you help me with that, it seem i`m only able to make vector field !!

Comment: Witch is nice looking but still not what i`m looking for (the vector field that is)

Comment: I would advise you to look up the following functions in the built-in documentation: Graphics3D, Arrow and perhaps Line, Text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting vectors originating from the origin in 3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4793/plotting-vectors-originating-from-the-origin-in-3d)

Comment: I really think is a duplicate of an earlier question. I am sorry to see it closed as a "simple error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really do need to read a lot of documentation, but perhaps this wil get you started. It will at least show you some the things you need to look up in the documentation.

First, *Mathematica* works in radians, not degrees, so conversion to radians must be done. The degree sign (°) is the conversion factor (π/180). It can be typed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>+deg+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

```
p = {250 Cos[60 °], 250 Cos[60 °], -250 Cos[45 °]}
```

> ```
>  {125, 125, -125 Sqrt[2]}
> ```

Next  *Mathematica*'s 3D graphics is based on classical geometric concepts such as points and lines, so `p` is a point not a  vector. To get a vector drawn the way you want, it will be necessary to draw an arrow that goes from the origin to `p`.

```
Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, p}]},
 PlotRange -> {{-250, 250}, {-250, 250}, {-250, 250}},
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 RotationAction -> "Clip",
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
 Axes -> True]
```

[image: arrow]